# Access the fun var value of one file into another fun or outside the fun of another python file?

Tags: oracle, pycharm, windows-10, python-3.8

I have three python files
Problem is i am trying to access the variable("username") defined in sample.py in test.py file so I can use the value of that this variable or any other variable and pass it to the function or if I can directly access the any variable value inside the function(test_target) of test.py

sample.py

```
from configparser import ConfigParser

parser = ConfigParser()
parser.read('config.ini')


def GetEnviornment():
    env = input("Enter Environment name : ") or 'Dev Site'
    return env

def GetConnectionString():
    env = GetEnviornment()
    username = parser.get(env, 'username')
    password = parser.get(env, 'password')
    dbname = parser.get(env, 'dbname')

    return "%s/%s@%s" % (username, password, dbname)
```

connection.py

```
import cx_Oracle
import sample

class Connection(cx_Oracle.Connection):

    def __init__(self):
        connectString = test.GetConnectionString()
        print("CONNECT to database")
        return super(Connection, self).__init__(connectString)

    def cursor(self):
        return Cursor(self)


class Cursor(cx_Oracle.Cursor):

    def execute(self, statement):
        print("EXECUTE", statement)
        return super(Cursor, self).execute(statement)

    def fetchall(self):
        print("FETCH ALL")
        return super(Cursor, self).fetchall()
```

test.py

```
from connection import *    
from sample import *

def test_target(user_suffix,hash_value):
    connection = Connection()
    cursor = connection.cursor()
    cursor.execute("select * from dba_users u where u.USERNAME like '{}'".format(username))
    rows = cursor.fetchall()
    for row in rows:
        print(row)
    cursor.close()
    connection.close()

user_suffix="Hello"
hash_value="12345"
test_target(user_suffix,hash_value)
```

Comment: For best help, edit this post and remove one of the questions. Create a new post asking it.

Comment: @ChristopherJones I made the changes in the post

Comment: I'll just comment on a couple of this.  First is the use of `'{}'` in the query.  *Never* do this when you can use bind variables, because it is insecure and impacts performance and scalability.  Use [bind variables](https://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/bind.html).  Second is that `cursor.connection.close()` is invalid.  I suggest you remove both `close()` lines and let the end-of-scope handle cleanup.

Comment: @ChristopherJones Yes cursor.connection.close() was invalid.it was typo. edited my original post

Comment: @ChristopherJones I need this variable value which comes from config.ini .I can't use the bind variable as my variable value changes as per the environment.

Comment: You can.  And must.  Using bind variables is not related to passing values around between files.

Comment: @ChristopherJones  not sure about must . the variable I m pulling is username and if someone else runs then it should pull his/her username from config.ini file and he just needs to change settings in one file & doesn’t need to look each and every function or files.It will helpful if you can provide the example

Comment: Getting values from files in a Python script has *no* relationship to how you pass those values to the database.  In both cases they will be stored in Python variables before you execute the SQL statement.  Use bind variables in the SQL statement.  cx_Oracle samples are [here](https://github.com/oracle/python-cx_Oracle/tree/master/samples) and documentation is [here](http://cx-oracle.readthedocs.org/en/latest/index.html).

Comment: @ChristopherJones  I think this will also solve the issue username = connection.username .we can pull the username from the connection string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made the changes in test.py.you can pull from the connection any entry which you want like username,dsn. There are other functions in Connection class

```
from connection import *    
from sample import *

def test_target(user_suffix,hash_value):
    connection = Connection()
    cursor = connection.cursor()
    username = connection.username
    cursor.execute("select * from dba_users u where u.USERNAME like '{}'".format(username))
    rows = cursor.fetchall()
    for row in rows:
        print(row)
    cursor.close()
    connection.close()

user_suffix="Hello"
hash_value="12345"
test_target(user_suffix,hash_value)
```